# Read/write in JetPack Compose

Tags: android

```
val path=Environment.getDataDirectory()
val letDirectory = File(path, "LET")
letDirectory.mkdirs()
var fi = File(path,"Records.txt")
fi.appendText("I am testing this ....")
val contents = fi.readText()
Text(contents)
```

My program gets crashed...Please help

I was writing code for jet pack compose....when I write code Android Empty Activity it...works ...
but It's failing when I try to do in Jetpack Compose

Comment: Hi,  what does the logcat says ? add error message to your question that you got in logcat

Answer (score 0):

check this out!:

```
val path=Environment.getDataDirectory()
val letDirectory = File(path, "LET")
letDirectory.mkdirs()
var fi = File(path,"Records.txt")
fi.appendText("I am testing this ....")
val contents = fi.readText()
Text(contents)
```

look...
you see? that i'ts the contest is wrong maybe get crashed,i'll try it but the code get crashed...Yes?/:|
maybe you can make a little bit i'ts good code, okay? there are no post at this thing. but i make code for you... okay?
like this:

```
var result by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
try {
            val fileInputStream = context.openFileInput("Records.txt")
            val inputReader = InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)
            val output = inputReader.readText()

            result = output
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
Text(text = result)
```

see...
the output its correct, try to do something :)
this code i'ts not get crashed in your phone.
try it!